# Connecting back automatically when there is a loss of connection

Tags: c#, .net, ibm-mq

We have a request to connect automatically when there is a connection failure(so that messages are not lost/neither its correlation ids).

Automatic reconnect to messages/MQ Manager via IBM MQ 7x client connected to IBM 6.x remote MQ server(don't have an option to upgrade 7x MQ server).

I tried doing

> if Manager is disconnected then  stop and reconnect

but this keeps losing the value of correlation ids.

I am using MQ.NET classes. Also, please advise if there is a manual reconnect possible, when there is a connection glitch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is always good to put all MQ method calls in a try/catch block and in the catch block, determine if the exception is connection error, then reconnect and reopen all the MQ objects that were open earlier. For example:

```
    public static void GetQueueName()
    {
        Hashtable mqProps = new Hashtable();
        MQQueueManager qm = null;
        String strCorrelId = "00123456789";
        MQQueue importQ = null;

        Reconnect:
        try
        {
            mqProps.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
            mqProps.Add(MQC.CHANNEL_PROPERTY, "NET.CHL");
            mqProps.Add(MQC.HOST_NAME_PROPERTY, "localhost");
            mqProps.Add(MQC.PORT_PROPERTY, 2099);

            qm = new MQQueueManager("QM1", mqProps);
        }
        catch (MQException mqex)
        {
            // Handle any exception appropriately
        }

        try
        {
            importQ = qm.AccessQueue("Q1", MQC.MQOO_INPUT_SHARED | MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT | MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING);

            MQMessage mqPutMsg = new MQMessage();
            mqPutMsg.WriteString("This is an import message");
            mqPutMsg.CorrelationId = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strCorrelId);
            MQPutMessageOptions mqpmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();
            mqpmo.Options = MQC.MQPMO_NEW_CORREL_ID;
            importQ.Put(mqPutMsg,mqpmo);

            MQMessage respMsg = new MQMessage();
            MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
            gmo.WaitInterval = 3000;
            gmo.Options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT;

                importQ.Get(respMsg, gmo);
            }
            catch (MQException ex)
            {
                switch(ex.ReasonCode)
                {
                    case MQC.MQRC_CONNECTION_BROKEN:
                    case MQC.MQRC_CONNECTION_ERROR:
                    case MQC.MQRC_CONNECTION_QUIESCING:
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                importQ.Close();
                                qm.Disconnect();
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex1)
                            {
                                // Ignore any exception
                            }
                            goto Reconnect;
                        }
                }
            }
            importQ.Close();                
            qm.Disconnect();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating reconnection logic for an MQ application is reasonably straight-forward.  I like to have a controller class and a worker class handle the reconnection logic.  Go look at Universal File Mover (UFM), http://www.capitalware.biz/ufm_overview.html and in particular the MQReceive Action.  Yes, UFM is written in Java but there is also no difference between Java/MQ code and C#/MQ code.  UFM is an open source project and the source code is available for download.

In particular, look at MQReceiveAction.java and MQGetMsg.java classes.  MQReceiveAction.java is the controller class and MQGetMsg.java is the worker class.  MQReceiveAction connects to the queue manager via MQGetMsg class.  When an MQException happens, MQReceiveAction disconnects via MQGetMsg from the queue manager and sleeps for 1 minute then attempts to reconnect to the queue manager.

> but this keeps losing the value of correlation ids.

Well, are you saving it in a class that is not getting thrown away/cleaned up?  In my example, if I needed to temporary save the CorrelID, I would simply have MQReceiveAction retrieve it from the worker class and when MQReceiveAction has successfully reconnected, push the CorrelID into the new worker class.

It is best to look at the problem from 10,000 feet and separate components it blocks.